# An equilateral triangle inscribed in an ellipse

Tags: equation-solving, geometry

```
Clear["'.*"]
{ecc, p, r1, t1} = {0.35, 1., 1.4, 0.8}
EQ = {p/r2 == 1 - ecc Cos[t2], p/r3 == 1 - ecc Cos[t3], 
  r1^2 + r2^2 - 2 r1 r2 Cos[t1 - t2] == 
   r3^2 + r2^2 - 2 r3 r2 Cos[t3 - t2], 
  r3^2 + r1^2 - 2 r3 r1 Cos[t3 - t1] == 
   r3^2 + r2^2 - 2 r3 r2 Cos[t3 - t2]}
NSolve[EQ, {r2, r3, t2, t3}]
```

First radius vector is given/defined in the first line. Also given are ellipse properties  ( $ecc, p =$ eccentricity and semi-latus rectum).

I am trying to inscribe an equilateral triangle in order to find two more vector arms $r2,r3$ along with their polar angles $ {t2,t3}. $

What assumptions or essential changes did I miss that makes this to hang? Is there a version problem?

The question has relevance to [this MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714306/equilateral-triangles-inscribed-in-ellipse).Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect I know what `ecc` and your other variables represent, but you might want to indicate what they're supposed to be for reference. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleEllipseInscribing.html) as well.

Comment: Yes sir, classical symbols of Newton planetary motion focal conic used.

Comment: Perhaps you did not see the image I just deleted or gone through the program. There are three radial arms. First one has length $1.4.$ Other two $(r2,r3)$ are unknown at start of computation. It would be also evident from the program. Feel free to say if my problem expression is in some way lacking.

Comment: Because I chose  origin / ellipse focus as reference of vectors starting , not its center of gravity. The link has an image of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NMinimize

```
NMinimize[{1, EQ}, {r2, r3, t2, t3}]
(*{1., {r2 -> 1.343, r3 -> 1.31612, t2 -> 0.75289, t3 -> 0.814458}}*)
```

Comment: you might try `FindInstance` as well..

Comment: Thanks,shall try it

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I wianted to plot a solution triangle. When plotted three points they do not form vertices of an equilateral triangle. Why so? Are inverse functions giving wrong choices?

Comment: @Narasimham: I don't think so. Please show your code, how you plot it...